# How to echo single value from multidimensional array when key is numeric?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Take this array as an example

```
Array
(
[events] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [event] => Array
                    (
                        [category] => seminars,sales
                        [status] => Live
```

How do I retrieve the value of category? I've tried various combinations such;

```
echo $array->events->events[0]->event->category;
```

So simple, yet I just can't figure it out.

Sorry for the lame question.

Comment: coding is not about combination .. lol

Comment: Marvelous Mark. Why the need to troll a genuine question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be

`echo $array['events'][0]['event']['category'];`

Comment: Who knows Probably bored trolls.

Answer (score 7):

You are using the object property selector.

Try this:

```
echo $array['events'][0]['event']['category'] ;
```

Comment: I do not get it, why the down vote? Who does this kind of things, down voting without leaving a comment? I urge SO to change there policy on this!

Comment: I had converted it from a object to an array previously, thank you for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

Try `echo $array['events'][0]['event']['category'];`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
echo $arr['events'][0]['event']['category'];
```